# Total (Tomcat) memory increasing but heap doesn't

Tags: java, tomcat, memory, memory-leaks

These are the memory options set for tomcat on the server:
-Xmx64g -Xms8g -XX:PermSize=768m -XX:MaxPermSize=768m

Over the last 1 month the total memory on the OS (Linux) has increased from 67GB to 95GB, a slow but gradual growth. (The only info I have right now is the zabbix (monitoring tool) showing the memory usage history since the server has since been restarted)

The only (user-)application running on this server is tomcat.

The same zabbix tool also shows java heap memory usage for the same period as  8GB, reaching max 16GB and then coming back to 8GB which is understandable. Our application logs also support the same.

But my question is that without the much increase in heap how is that the total memory has been increasing gradually?
(I am referring to total memory instead of tomcat because that was the zabbix tool is showing and nothing else than tomcat is running on this machine)
Is there a memory leak somewhere?
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Without further inspection of your system it's hard to say what's going on there. Let's approach this from a different angle:

If you say that your application runs well with 8-16G of RAM, there's no reason to provide it with 64G of maximum memory. You're allowing the JVM to allocate quite a lot of memory that you don't expect it to use - however, it's free to do so. It might well run for loooong time with no garbage collection at all, then stop the world for a long time to do its garbage collection. In the web world you rather want more frequent but extremely quick GC runs - rather than infrequent and long running. Thus the dimensions of the Java Heap Maximum should be calculated as *"minimum the application needs plus some safety measures for sudden higher demand"* rather than *"maximum the server can provide minus some space so that other (system management) applications can run occasionally"*

Following this principle your initial question won't be a problem any more.

Coming back to your question: `-Xmx` [does not denote](http://javaguru.fi/why-is-my-java-process-taking-more-memory-than-i-gave-it.html) the maximum memory your process ever claims from the operating system. It's just the maximum heap space that will be available to the application. Add various other memory (threads, PermGen, others) to it to get the amount that a JVM actually allocates from the OS.

Comment: Olaf Kock, Your recommendation about limiting heap memory does make sense. I also understand that the total memory a java process takes is always more than the java heap allocated. total memory=heap+perm+jni+etc. But what we are seeing here is gradual increase in total memory over a period of time but very limited/no increase in heap. My question is would there be a memory leak?